# viewing and editing the parameters of a result

Tags: python, neo4j

In my result query, I am presented with a series of results nodes.

I am able to loop through them and print the node to the display.
Now I need to display only a single KVP of the properties

This is the results of printing the node

<Record n=<Node id=322810 labels=frozenset({'N32W118'}) properties={'R': 'R0', 'U': 'U1', 'LC': 'L02', 'Deck': 'D001_S100_T001', 'Filename': 'N32W118_D001_S100_T001_L02_U1_R0.tif', 'lon': '-117.9998779296875', 'units': 'None', 'URI': 'C:\projects\python\high_res\data\tiles\N32\W118\001_Elevation\L02\U1\N32W118_D001_S100_T001_L02_U1_R0.tif', 'lat': '32.4996337890625', 'Name': 'N32W118'}>>

The value I need is from the property U

How can I grab that value?

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2:

There are at least three ways to do it.
Assuming your last line of the query is `RETURN n`, you are returning a list of nodes.
Three simple options are:

```
1.`RETURN n`
2.`RETURN n.U, n.R, n.LC`
3.`RETURN {U: n.U, R: n.R, LC: n.LC}`
```

The 1st one is using the schema according to your python package. On [`neomodel`](https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you need to [`inflate`](https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module_documentation.html?highlight=inflate#neomodel.relationship.StructuredRel.inflate) it.
The 2nd one will return a list of values according to the properties U,R,LC, per each node (so a list of lists).
The 3rd one will return a list of jsons according to the properties U,R,LC, per each node (so a list of json). This will probably be strings of a json format and will require `json.loads` in order to be used as a json.

For example, for data:

```
MERGE (b:Node{U:2, R:4, LC: 7})
MERGE (c:Node{U:1, R:9, LC: 45})
MERGE (d:Node{U:6, R:2, LC: 56})
```

You can run query:

```
MATCH(n)
RETURN n.U, n.R, n.LC
```

And get a result:

```
╒═════╤═════╤══════╕
│"n.U"│"n.R"│"n.LC"│
╞═════╪═════╪══════╡
│2    │4    │7     │
├─────┼─────┼──────┤
│1    │9    │45    │
├─────┼─────┼──────┤
│6    │2    │56    │
└─────┴─────┴──────┘
```

or run:

```
MATCH(n)
RETURN {U: n.U, R: n.R, LC: n.LC}
```

And get a result:

```
╒════════════════════════════╕
│"{U: n.U, R: n.R, LC: n.LC}"│
╞════════════════════════════╡
│{"LC":7,"R":4,"U":2}        │
├────────────────────────────┤
│{"LC":45,"R":9,"U":1}       │
├────────────────────────────┤
│{"LC":56,"R":2,"U":6}       │
└────────────────────────────┘
```

The 3rd option, regardless of the schema, is similar to .lean() on mongodb and mongoose.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to work with these values in python, after the result is returned.

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly.